# Accidentally deleted a product in the admin panel，how can I get it back?

Tags: mysql, magento

Last night I modified the description of a product in the admin panel, and I carelessly deleted one product. I want to get it back. I tried using the product backup CSV file to get it back at the admin panel but I found that it didn't work. I'm very confused when I import products in the admin panel, what format data does it need? Do you have some good ideas to help me to get the accidentally deleted product back?

I am using the Magento VERSION 1.5.1.0

automatically admin panel， browser to system -> import/export -> import (see image)

[image]

Comment: Your question needs more explanation, which admin panel you are using, some php cms or some rails etc. Which OS your server has. Please provide with more details.

Comment: tags say magento... just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all please specify what does it mean

```
but eventully I find that it doesn't work
```

Well what I would suggest you to do now: if product is simple, simply recreate on on the basis of backup CSV.

If you don't want then please specify, how do you do your backup and why this file don't work?
Perhaps you simply should clean cache and reindex.

Comment: I backed up through the control panel，browser：system->Import/Export Profile->Export All Products

->run profile.

Comment: And what doesn't working? what it keeps saying or what? Try to leave only headers and string with your prodcut.